# Trying to target a specific line in a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a daily CSV file with the same basic structure each time. I am chipping parts of it each week off and into my database. I find most of the data with specific conditional searches, so to speak.

These do grab the information I need, but I've come across one instance in particular where this isn't going to grab what I want, because the data is on a line and column separate from the header.

Here is an example:

```
$file = fopen($fname, "r");
while(! feof($file)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($file);
    if (strtotime($data[0]) == true && (!empty($data[12]))) {
        $sql = "UPDATE numbers
                    SET tot='" . $data[13] . "'
                WHERE date = '" . $lastDay . "'";
           if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "<li><p>" . $conn -> affected_rows . " newly created record in <u>tot</u>.</p></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, read a line and dont do anything with it

Comment: Not really enough code here to be any use

Comment: _"Is there a way to start reading from the very next line if the condition is met rather than that line?"_ Set a flag when the condition happens. Don't process lines unless the flag is set.

Comment: I'll edit some more in...

Comment: You could also skip to the next line using [`fseek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php). e.g. `fseek($file, 1, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule would that go inside the if statement?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the given `UPDATE`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injections. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: This is my personal website. Its only for my use and is password protected. When I finish this page I'll go back in and work on security.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, read the next line from the CSV if that is the line that conains the data you are interested in. And it is not difficult to use MYSQLI_ correctly and prepare and bind queries.

```
$file = fopen($fname,"r");

// prepare the query ONCE, it can then be run multiple times with an execute
// and new values applied to the ? each time with the bind_param()
$sql = "UPDATE numbers SET tot = ? WHERE date = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


while(! feof($file)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($file);
    if (strtotime($data[0]) == true && (!empty($data[12]))) {
        // read next line, as dont want the one we tested        
        $data = fgetcsv($file);

        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $data[13], $lastday);
        // execute of an UPDATE returns true if it worked and false if it failed
        $res = $stmt->execute();
        if ($res) {
            // NOTE: UPDATE does not create a new row, it amends an existing one
            //echo "<li><p>" . $conn -> affected_rows . " newly created record in <u>tot</u>.</p></li>";
            echo "<li><p>" . $conn->affected_rows . " rows updated <u>tot</u>.</p></li>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that just echoing it out and it's grabbing the same line: ```$file = fopen($fname,"r");
while(! feof($file)) {
    // Found it
  $data = fgetcsv($file);
  if ($data[0] == "OTHER CHARGES") {
   $data = fgetcsv($file);
   echo $data[0] . ' and ' . $data[1];
   }
}`` It echos out the OTHER CHARGES

Comment: You did see there is now a new `$data = fgetcsv($file);` after the IF didn't you?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us an example of the file you are processing and then say which line you want to find and then which line you want to use in the query

Comment: I apologize. I didnt send up the edited file. It works perfect. And I appreciate the security edits you made as well. Thank you!